# Required field HTML5 form

Tags: forms, html, validation, required

I just created html 5 form with attribute "required".

Why it still appear popup "Please fill out this field" in **left top of my browser(Firefox), not under the field**  when it submitted although all field filled.

here my code :

```
<form method="get" id="form_reg_mem">
                        <input type="hidden" name="s" value="member"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="a" value="4"/>
                        <h5>member Informatio</h5>
                        <hr/><br/>
                        <p>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input id="mem_email" class="easyui-validatebox filter_email" type="email" name="mem_email" required style="width: 200px" maxlength="45" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input id="mem_fname" class="easyui-validatebox filter_alphanumeric" type="text" name="mem_fname" required style="width: 200px" maxlength="45"/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input id="mem_lname" class="easyui-validatebox filter_alphanumeric" type="text" name="mem_lname" required style="width: 200px"  maxlength="45" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <textarea id="mem_addr" class="easyui-validatebox filter_alphanumeric" name="mem_addr" style="width: 400px" maxlength="128"></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <input id="mem_phone" class="easyui-validatebox filter_numeric" type="text" name="mem_phone" style="width: 150px" maxlength="32" required/>
                        <p>                               
                            <label>Member Class</label>
                            <input id="mem_class" name="mem_class" url="/mobmarket/json/class.json" valueField="id" textField="text">  
                            </input>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input class="button" value="Register" type="submit"/>
                        </p>
                     </form>
```

Thx

Comment: i just edit my post and you can see my code
thx

Comment: It works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/jbg6h/  I just see the message once

Answer (score 2):

Finally i know what my trouble.
It because i use the "[easy ui combo box element](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/form/form2.php)" as a required field
Dont add required attribut if you use it

You must use this code to make it required

```
 $("some selector").combobox({
                required:true
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute should be

```
required="required"
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? Your code in the question works fine for me in FF and Chrome latest

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by mbuurman is correct. Adding required="required" atribute to the input and select tags it worked ok for me. Tested on Chrome (30.0) and Firefox (24.0).